# Python loop in a list returning wrong answer

Tags: python, api, for-loop, pagination

I have a code that uses a request to an api :

```
lists = [254,255,256]
length = len(lists)
  
for li in range(length):
  for count in range(4):
    #o start dentro de url é o counter. Ou seja, ele vai até 4, a partir do 0. O lists[li] é o id, logo ele faz um loop de 0 a 5 pra cada id e colheta as informações para transformar em DATA JSON
    url = "https://((site-name))/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/{}/tarefa?start={}&limit=50".format(lists[li], count)
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json() 
    unidades(data)
```

At the url, the first {} is the ID of the project, and the second {} is the pagination

Code continuation :

```
def unidades(data):
  nome = []
  for i in data['data']:
    nome.append(i['nome'])
```

When I run this code, the code returns only the last count loop from the url (the last page from the pagination)

If instead of using append, I use list:

```
def unidades(data):
  for i in data['data']:
    print(i['nome'])
```

With the print, the code returns all the infos about all the pages, different from the list, that only returns my last page. How can i have the list all the infos about all the pages, like the output from the print ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: Thanks, i will try to get out of this habit. This range is specific, i can use dynamic too, like if the page returns nothing, stop the while loop for example. But first i need to solve this list problem, that only returns last page, while de print returns everything

Comment: I'm talking about `for li in range(length)`, that should be `for item in lists:`

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `unidades()` you start with an empty `nome` list. `unidades()` should take the list as a parameter and add to that, so the names from the previous call will persist.

```
def unidades(data, nome):
    for i in data['data']:
        nome.append(i['nome'])

lists = [254,255,256]
length = len(lists)
nomes = []

for li in lists:
    for count in range(4):
        #o start dentro de url é o counter. Ou seja, ele vai até 4, a partir do 0. O li é o id, logo ele faz um loop de 0 a 5 pra cada id e colheta as informações para transformar em DATA JSON
        url = "https://((site-name))/api/v1/implantacao/projeto/{}/tarefa?start={}&limit=50".format(li, count)
        print(url)
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        data = response.json() 
        unidades(data, nomes)

print(nomes)
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, appreciate your time and help my friend. Really saved me, it was an easy question but i was struggling at it. I will keep growing